# Accessing safari session data from iOs app

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, session

I have a web page that redirects to the appstore, once the user has installed the app I'd like it to go fetch some data based on a parameter passed to the web page.
so http://myapp.com/?q=123 redirects to app store for app installation, once the app is opened it should go fetch data from something like http://myapp.com/data/123
Would it be possible to start a session on the web page and store the 123 there, and then make a call from the app to any page on the domain and retrieve the 123 from there?

Comment: Maybe tell us a bit more, like is this user already 'known' to you on the website to some means?

Comment: No the page is just a landing page and there's no database at all as of now, we have no clue on who could land there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know it is not possible to pass some value to the appstore that will then somehow be retained for the app when/if it is installed. What you will have to do is find some means of identifying the user or device both on your site and in the app. Anything from a username, email, facebook account will do. Anything like device ID and MAC addresses are pretty much off limits as well, if not impossible. I hope this helps, or maybe there is another solution out there that I do not know of.

Comment: Yes I tought about it before and it seems to me the only stuff I can use is IP address and ios version (from user agent) and it's not enough for the scale of our app to prevent issues with duplication.